# converting comma separated string to comma separated number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting comma separated string as `2019,15,7` - from backend. need to convert as comma separated numbers like `2019, 15, 7` is there a shorthand for this?

any one help me with shortest approach?

Comment: that second one is also a string. Do you mean `2019`, `15` and `7`?

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: If the backend is trying to send you a date, have them send you a date! Don't jump through multiple hoops to get the date.

Comment: @Martijn - yes need to convert as number

Comment: @Jamiec - are you answering or advising here? it's all differs the people

Comment: `"2019,15,7".split(",").map(x => parseInt(x));`

Comment: @Martijn - you are correct, But I thought that we can't directly pass array in to date object.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Martijn said, you use split and parseInt.

If you then need to use those numbers in a Date constructor you could do it like this

```
const [y,d,m] = "2019,15,7".split(',').map(x => parseInt(x));
const myDate = new Date(y,m-1,d);
```

Bear in mind the month goes from 0 to 11 in the constructor.

Comment: Missing `const/let` declarations.